# Picking multiple choices from an enum

Tags: unity

I recall in a certain code, there were named constants with exponential values. Two constants' values could be added two include both of them in one go.

Example:

{ STR = 1, AGI = 2, INT = 4}
From this, combining the enumerations would always give a unique number, which lets us identify "3" as "STR&AGI" and 5 as "STR&INT".

How I would implement this is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Flags` decoration

```
 // Powers of two
[Flags] public enum AttackType {
    // Decimal     // Binary
    None   = 0,    // 000000
    Melee  = 1,    // 000001
    Fire   = 2,    // 000010
    Ice    = 4,    // 000100
    Poison = 8     // 001000
}
```

Then use a bitwise operator like OR

```
attackType = AttackType.Melee | AttackType.Fire;
// OR
attackType = AttackType.Melee;
attackType |= AttackType.Fire;
```

Source: A blog post by Alan Zucconi about this argument:

http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/

You'll get all the answers you need about this topic there.

Comment: Link only answers are not well received. If that link dies and goes 404, your answer does not contain the necessary information to answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

This is called a Flags enumeration.

You mark it with the `System.Flags` attribute, and give it a backing type that's some kind of integer:

```
[System.Flags]
public enum Characteristics : int {
   None    = 0x00,
   Heavy   = 0x01,
   Hot     = 0x02,
   Shiny   = 0x04,
   Squishy = 0x08,
   Loud    = 0x10,
   Large   = 0x20
}
```

You can then stack multiple flags in a single variable with an OR operator:

```
var myCharacteristics = Characteristics.Loud | Characteristics.Squishy;
```

or stack on more later with `myCharacteristics |= Characteristics.Shiny;`

You can check for the presence of a particular flag with an AND operator:

```
if((myCharacteristics & Characteristics.Loud) != Characteristics.None)
    Debug.Log("I am loud");
```

or for any of a group of flags

```
var conspicuous = Characteristics.Shiny | Characteristics.Large | Characteristics.Loud;

if((myCharacteristics & conspicuous) != Characteristics.None)
    Debug.Log("I am conspicuous");
```

To edit this properly in the Unity inspector, you can [define a custom PropertDrawer like the one shown here](https://gist.github.com/ChemiKhazi/11395776) (modified below to work with the new `EnumFlagsField` instead of `EnumMaskField`) and mark your variable with an attribute:

```
[EnumFlags]
public Characteristics myCharacteristics;
```

[image: Image of Unity Inspector showing multi-select of flags in an enum]

Here are the scripts to make this work:

EnumFlagsAttribute - place in your Assets folder.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EnumFlagsAttribute : PropertyAttribute {
    public string enumName;

    public EnumFlagsAttribute() { }

    public EnumFlagsAttribute(string name) {
        enumName = name;
    }
}
```

EnumFlagsDrawer - place in an Assets sub-folder called "Editor" so it's not compiled into the game:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(EnumFlagsAttribute))]
public class EnumFlagsDrawer : PropertyDrawer {
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        EnumFlagsAttribute flagSettings = (EnumFlagsAttribute)attribute;
        Enum targetEnum = GetBaseProperty<Enum>(property);

        string propName = flagSettings.enumName;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propName))
            propName = property.name;

        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
        var enumNew = EditorGUI.EnumFlagsField(position, propName, targetEnum);
        property.intValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(enumNew, targetEnum.GetType());
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    static T GetBaseProperty<T>(SerializedProperty prop) {
        // Separate the steps it takes to get to this property
        string[] separatedPaths = prop.propertyPath.Split('.');

        // Go down to the root of this serialized property
        System.Object reflectionTarget = prop.serializedObject.targetObject as object;
        // Walk down the path to get the target object
        foreach (var path in separatedPaths) {
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = reflectionTarget.GetType().GetField(path);
            reflectionTarget = fieldInfo.GetValue(reflectionTarget);
        }
        return (T)reflectionTarget;
    }
}
```

---

Edit: based on a [link from the article Galandil shared](http://www.sharkbombs.com/2015/02/17/unity-editor-enum-flags-as-toggle-buttons/), here's a different way to draw the flags in the inspector. I souped up the linked version to support different enum backing types, multi-object editing, and multiple rows in a single enum. It will also skip over "None" or compound flags. Still experimental, but it seems to work.

[image: Flags displayed as toggle buttons]

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(EnumFlagsAttribute))]
public class EnumFlagsAttributeDrawer : PropertyDrawer {


    [System.Flags]
    enum TriBool {
        Unset = 0,
        False =  1,
        True = 2,
        Both = 3
    }

    struct Entry {
        public string label;
        public int mask;
        public TriBool currentValue;
    }

    List<SerializedProperty> _properties;
    List<Entry> _entries;
    int _rowCount;
    int _columnCount;

    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        if (_properties == null)
            Initialize(property);
        return _rowCount * EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        label = EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        Rect labelRect = new Rect(
            position.x, 
            position.y, 
            EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, 
            position.height);
        EditorGUI.LabelField(labelRect, label);

        float buttonStride = (position.width - labelRect.width) / _columnCount;
        float buttonWidth = buttonStride * 1.0f;
        Rect buttonRect = new Rect(
            labelRect.max.x, 
            labelRect.y, 
            buttonWidth,
            EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight);

        int column = 0;

        GUIStyle mixedButton = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
        mixedButton.normal.textColor = Color.grey;

        for(int i = 0; i < _entries.Count; i++) {
            //Debug.Log(_entries[i].label + " : " + _entries[i].currentValue);
            var entry = _entries[i];

            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            bool pressed = GUI.Toggle(
                buttonRect, 
                entry.currentValue == TriBool.True, 
                entry.label, 
                entry.currentValue == TriBool.Both ? mixedButton : GUI.skin.button);

            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()) {

                if (pressed) {
                    foreach (var prop in _properties)
                        prop.intValue |= entry.mask;
                    entry.currentValue = TriBool.True;
                } else {
                    foreach (var prop in _properties)
                        prop.intValue &= ~entry.mask;
                    entry.currentValue = TriBool.False;
                }
                _entries[i] = entry;
            }

            buttonRect.x += buttonStride;
            if(++column >= _columnCount) {
                column = 0;
                buttonRect.x = labelRect.max.x;
                buttonRect.y += buttonRect.height;
            }
        }

        foreach (var prop in _properties)
            prop.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();

        EditorGUI.showMixedValue = false;
    }

    void Initialize(SerializedProperty property) {
        var allTargetObjects = property.serializedObject.targetObjects;
        _properties = new List<SerializedProperty>(allTargetObjects.Length);
        foreach (var targetObject in allTargetObjects) {
            SerializedObject iteratedObject = new SerializedObject(targetObject);
            SerializedProperty iteratedProperty = iteratedObject.FindProperty(property.propertyPath);
            if (iteratedProperty != null)
                _properties.Add(iteratedProperty);
        }

        var parentType = property.serializedObject.targetObject.GetType();
        var fieldInfo = parentType.GetField(property.propertyPath);
        var enumType = fieldInfo.FieldType;
        var trueNames = System.Enum.GetNames(enumType);

        var typedValues = GetTypedValues(property, enumType);
        var display = property.enumDisplayNames;
        var names = property.enumNames;

        _entries = new List<Entry>();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) {
            int sortedIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(trueNames, names[i]);
            int value = typedValues[sortedIndex];
            int bitCount = 0;  

            for (int temp = value; (temp != 0 && bitCount <= 1); temp >>= 1)
                bitCount += temp & 1;

            //Debug.Log(names[i] + ": " + value + " ~ " + bitCount);

            if (bitCount != 1)
                continue;

            TriBool consensus = TriBool.Unset;
            foreach (var prop in _properties) {
                if ((prop.intValue & value) == 0)
                    consensus |= TriBool.False;
                else
                    consensus |= TriBool.True;
            }

            _entries.Add(new Entry { label = display[i], mask = value, currentValue = consensus });
        }

        _rowCount = Mathf.CeilToInt(_entries.Count / 4f);
        _columnCount = Mathf.Min(_entries.Count, (Mathf.CeilToInt(_entries.Count / 3f) == _rowCount) ? 3 : 4);
    }

    int[] GetTypedValues(SerializedProperty property, System.Type enumType) {
        var values = System.Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        var underlying = System.Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);

        if (underlying == typeof(int))
            return ConvertFrom<int>(values);
        else if (underlying == typeof(uint))
            return ConvertFrom<uint>(values);
        else if (underlying == typeof(short))
            return ConvertFrom<short>(values);
        else if (underlying == typeof(ushort))
            return ConvertFrom<ushort>(values);
        else if (underlying == typeof(sbyte))
            return ConvertFrom<sbyte>(values);
        else if (underlying == typeof(byte))
            return ConvertFrom<byte>(values);
        else
            throw new System.InvalidCastException("Cannot use enum backing types other than byte, sbyte, ushort, short, uint, or int.");
    }

    int[] ConvertFrom<T>(System.Array untyped) where T : System.IConvertible {
        var typedValues = new int[untyped.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < typedValues.Length; i++)
            typedValues[i] = System.Convert.ToInt32((T)untyped.GetValue(i));

        return typedValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I declare flag Enums I usually use bit shifting rather than hexadecimal as the assignment to make it more obvious what the values are and how they fit together, eg `Heavy = 1 << 0, Hot = 1 << 1` etc.